# Message Type ID for subtitles in RTMP packet

Tags: rtmp

I am looking for messageType id for subtitles in a RTMP packet.

I tried looking up, but didnt find any info about this.

http://wiki.multimedia.cx/?title=RTMP
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol

Answer (score 0):

There is no messageType for subtitles. You can send them in a script tag, or as an SEI NALU in the AVC ES.